# Fixed height on <tr> when <table> height is 100%

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to set the row heights in a table when the table height is 100%. I can accomplish this when the table height is unset but that brings the footer up with it which is not the desired effect as the footer should be at the bottom of the parent container.

The height of the rows should be set at 49px instead of dividing themselves evenly to fill the entire space.

Here is the html and css (to see the actual issue use the codesandbox.io link below):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

thead {
  height: 49px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

thead>th {
  height: 49px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: lightblue;
  border-bottom: solid;
}

tr {
  height: 49px;
}

tr>td {
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: solid;
}

tfoot {
  background: lightblue;
}

tfoot>td {
  height: 49px;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <td colspan="5">I am the footer deal with it</td>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-matan-fklp03?file=/index.html

Comment: Please always include all relevant code in the question itself and not just as external link. Additional providing `codesandbox.io` is fine, but not as the only source to get the code.

Comment: @MisterJojo thank you for the comment but what element would you suggest I put min-height on? The table element

Comment: tried `tr: { min-height: 49px }` and `tr > td { min-height: 49px }` by themselves and together but that did not fix the issue.

Comment: you need to add a TR  in thead

Comment: you need to add a TR in tfoot  too

Comment: If you want `<tr>`  height at exactly 49px each and the `<table>` at 100% height then .parent should be height of 245px.

Answer (score 0):

> *"The height of the rows should be set at 49px instead of dividing themselves evenly to fill the entire space."*

### Problems

- `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` had no `<tr>` which is required otherwise HTML is invalid.
- `position: sticky`, `top: 0`, and `bottom: 0` were assigned to `<td>` and `<th>` See note 3️⃣.
- `<table>` height is 100% of `.parent` ⟶ `.parent` height is 100% of `<body>` ⟶ `<body>` height is 100% of `<html>`. So `<table>` at 100% height means that it's height is going to vary according to the height of `.parent`. That's why the rows in `<tbody>` were 60px each.

### Solutions

- Added `<tr>` to `<tfoot>` and `<thead>`
- Assigned fixed height to `.parent` and `<table>` as well as `overflow-y: scroll` so `<table>` scrolls within the borders of `.parent` marked 2️⃣.
- Added a CSS ruleset that resets dimension properties for everything marked  1️⃣
- There's 3 CSS rulesets that are added for sticky `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` marked 3️⃣.
- All `<tr>` are 49px marked 4️⃣ See **Figure I**
  **Figure I**
  [image]

**Note:** 7 extra rows were added to demonstrate the "sticky" functionality.

<kbd>[Plunker<sup>❉</sup>](https://plnkr.co/edit/Eddapd04skicFsaO?open=lib%2Fscript.js)</kbd><kbd>[CodePen](https://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/QWQexPg)</kbd><kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/wys6pqxm/)</kbd>

<sup>❉</sup><sup>Click the green "Preview" button</sup>

```css
* {
  /* 1️⃣ */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  /* 2️⃣ */
  max-height: 245px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
  /* 2️⃣ */
  max-height: 245px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

thead,
tfoot {
  /* 3️⃣ */
  position: sticky;
  background: lightblue;
}

thead {
  /* 3️⃣ */
  top: 0;
}

tfoot {
  /* 3️⃣ */
  bottom: 0;
}

tr {
  /* 4️⃣ */
  height: 49px;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<section class='parent'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
        <th>Col 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 1 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 2 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 3 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 3 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 4 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 4 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 4 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 4 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 4 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 5 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 5 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 5 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 5 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 5 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 6 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 6 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 6 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 6 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 6 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 7 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 7 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 7 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 7 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 7 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 8 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 8 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 8 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 8 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 8 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 9 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 9 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 9 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 9 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 9 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 10 Col 1</td>
        <td>Row 10 Col 2</td>
        <td>Row 10 Col 3</td>
        <td>Row 10 Col 4</td>
        <td>Row 10 Col 5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">I am the footer bow before my might!</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</section>
```

Comment: I copied your code into codesandbox.io removed a few rows and they are still expanding to fit the height. See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-matan-fklp03?file=/index.html

Comment: Just updated check it out.

Comment: @CraigHowell Updated again. I included 3 links to 3 different sites with this answer and the results are the same as it is on SO. I looked at anything obvious in the CodeSandbox version and I didn't notice anything different. I'm not familiar with CodeSandbox so I couldn't find a link to the resource page.